# How to prove\disprove the existence of a function s.t. $g'(x)=-g^2(x), g(x)\neq0$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I tried to disprove the existence of such function using MVT and got stuck.. am I in the right direction? the function should be defined over all real numbers.

$$g'(x)=-g^2(x), g(x)\neq0$$

Comment: Hint: Consider $g(x) = \frac{a}{{1 + ax}},\quad a \ne 0$.

Comment: But that would mean that $g$ is not defined for all real numbers, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that condition.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dg}{dx}=-g^2$$ $$-\int \frac{dg}{g^2}=\int dx$$
$$\frac{1}{g}=x+c$$ $$g(x)=\frac{1}{x+c}$$
This function is not defined at $x=-c.$ There is no such function.

Comment: Which function did you integrate?

Comment: Both..............

Comment: I didn't really get it... can you explain further?